# Bundle install and yarn install inside entry script - Docker

Tags: ruby-on-rails, docker, docker-compose

I see that `bundle install` and `yarn install` are usually done in Dockerfile as:

```
RUN bundle install && yarn install
```

Which means that if I modify Gemfile or yarn.lock, I need to re-build the image again. I know that there is layer caching and the docker build will not rebuild other layers except bundle install && yarn install layer. But it means I have to do `docker-compose up -d --build`

But I was wondering if it is ok to put these commands inside an entry script of docker-compose or in command as:

```
command: bundle install && yarn install && rails s
```

In this way, I believe, whenever I do `docker-compose up -d`, `bundle install` and `yarn install` will be executed without having to build the image.

Not sure if it has any advantages over conventional bundle install in Dockerfile except not having to append `--build` in `docker-compose up`. Correct that if I do this, bundle install and yarn install will get executed even when there are no changes to Gemfile or Yarn files. I guess this is one of the bad sides.

Please correct me if it is not the ideal way to go.

*New to docker world.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It wastes several minutes of time and uses up network bandwidth every time you start your application.  When you're doing local development, it'd be the equivalent of doing this, *every* time you run the application:

```sh
rm -rf vendor node_modules
bundle install              # from scratch
yarn install                # from scratch
bundle exec rails s
```

A core part of Docker is rebuilding images (in the same way that languages like Go, Java, Typescript, *etc.* have a "build" phase).  Trying to avoid image rebuilds isn't usually advisable.  With a well-written Dockerfile, and particularly for an interpreted language, running `docker build` should be fairly efficient.

The one important trick is to separately copy the files that specify dependencies, and the rest of your application.  As soon as a Dockerfile `COPY` instruction encounters a file that's changed it will disable layer caching for the rest of the application.  Since dependencies change relatively infrequently, a sequence that first copies the dependency file, then installs the dependencies, then copies the application can jump straight to the last step if the dependency file hasn't changed.

```sh
COPY Gemfile Gemfile.lock ./
RUN bundle install

COPY package.json yarn.lock ./
RUN yarn install

COPY . ./
```

(Make sure to include the Bundler `vendor` directory and the `node_modules` directory in a `.dockerignore` file so the last `COPY` step doesn't overwrite what previously got installed.)

Comment: "wastes several minutes of time and uses up network bandwidth". Of course. Thank you for the explanation. And good point about including node_modules directory in .dockerignore. I have been doing it in .gitignore but forgot about this one.

But what about vendor. AFAIK, it houses 3rd party libraries and shouldn't they be copied as well to docker image?

Comment: `bundle install` will install them for you; you want to exclude them from the Docker build context for the same reason as the `node_modules` directory.

Answer (score 1):

This question is opinion based. As you already found out yourself, it is a common practice to install dependencies (bundle, yarn, others) during the image build process, and not image run process.

The rationale is that you `run` more times than you `build`, and you want the run operation to start quickly.

In the same way that you do `apt install...` or `yum install...` in the build stage, you should normally do `bundle install` in the build stage as well.

That said, if it makes sense to you to `bundle install` as a part of the entrypoint, that is your choice. I suspect that after you do it, you will see that it is less common for a reason.

Another note about docker layers: If the Gemfile change, not only the layer that refers to it will change, but all subsequent layers as well. For that reason, it is often common to separate the copy of the dependencies manifest (`Gemfile.*`) from the copying of the app, like this:

```
# Pre-install gems
COPY Gemfile* ./
RUN gem install bundler && \
    bundle install --jobs=3 --retry=3 

# Copy the rest of the app
COPY . .
```

So this way, if your app files change, but not the dependencies, the build will be faster.

Comment: "not only the layer that refers to it will change, but all subsequent layers as well". That is true. 
And as I mentioned, "bundle install and yarn install will get executed even when there are no changes to Gemfile or Yarn files", which WILL delay the run as you mentioned.

Thank you for a great explanation @DannyB.